# Remove border from a DatePicker in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to know if there is any way to remove this border with css.
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `DatePicker.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 0");`

Comment: Edge was not hidden :(

Comment: This is something else that may work, `DataPicker.setStyle("-fx-border-color: transparent;");`

Comment: Just what i need!

Comment: Glad that this helped:)